# ELECTRON - Load local HTML file containing a script tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, fs

I'm relatively new to Node and Electron so I could be way off on this.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is create a SPA that has a main navigation and the user can click on the links which will load local HTML files that contain a script tag. Currently I have a main page that uses fs to grab the html files and load it into a div successfully but none of the JS in that retrieved file works. I’m doing it this way because I need to interact with the UI and add dynamic elements

this is what I have for code:

*mainWindow.html*

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'fragments/main/welcome.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

*welcome.html*

```
<section class="main-content-wide">
<h1>Welcome to my app</h1>
<p id="datetimeGreeting"></p>
<p id="funFact"></p>
<script>
    console.log('Hello world');
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

*edit: if someone has a better way or a “best practice” way, I’d love to hear it.*

Comment: why not to write your html file content directly into your div and toggle its display attribute on a button click?

Comment: You could not load js or any other file by programmatically i main process.

Comment: I updated my posts after reading your comments - the reason why I need the script tag is to be able to interact with the DOM

Comment: does anything speak against using an iframe for your own local content or if it is remote content - using a browserview?

Comment: I generally try to avoid iframes; browserview opens a new window if I'm not mistaken - I want it to be open like "tab". I'm going back to the drawing board on this though - I'm going to keep this post open until I find a solution and once I do - I'll post it here incase anyone else has the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work, Try it and let me know.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'fragments/main/welcome.html'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
            var scripts = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName("script");
            for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
              eval(scripts[i].innerText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just a heads up - It works exactly as it should. I really appreciate it. Now if this is a good idea to set my app up in this way is a god idea or not - I'll have to do some digging but this'll help me along. Thanks!

Comment: No, this is far away from the better solution. You should find other alternative.

Comment: From the looks of it - I could just put all my front end logic in a render JS file